# How do I do a revert in git?

Tags: git

The following pops up from git bash when I try to execute a git revert. How do I get this to acutally do the revert?

[image]

Comment: If you do not want nano to show, use `-m "write commit message"` with the command.

Answer (score 3):

This is the command-line text editor "nano", presented to you to adjust the commit message, if needed.

Press Ctrl+O (and Enter) to save the file.
Then Ctrl+X to close the editor.

After saving and closing the editor, git will create a commit that reverts the changes of whatever commit you specified in the command.

Answer (score 0):

[git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) works by committing one or more *new* changes to reverse changes made via previous commits.  Just like for any commit, it wants you to provide a commit message, and since you didn't specify one on the command line, it opened up the configured editor to give you a place to enter the commit message, complete with a default message.

Edit the commit message if you like.  Save the message and exit the editor normally to proceed, just as you would for a `git commit`.